# Sharepoint: SPAttachmentCollection a collection of what exactly?

Tags: c#, sharepoint

Take the following code snippet:

```
SPAttachmentCollection attachments = item.Attachments ;
```

What exactly is SPAttachmentCollection a collection of? Most collections tell you what they're a collection of.... but remember the golden rule of SharePoint - that's right, if its possible to break, its already broken.

In case you're wondering an SPAttachment object does not exist. So could someone please enlighten me, what is the attachment object I am looking for.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.binarywave.com/blogs/eshupps/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=26

"the SPAttachmentCollection is simply an array of strings representing the file name of each attachment"

Comment: Thanks... its true, but I've discovered there is more to it than that... still I will mark your answer as correct, because at face value it is....

Answer (score 20):

Note that the linked post complicates things. The preferred usage is found in the comments:

```
var attachments in item.Attachments;
foreach (string fileName in attachments)
{
    SPFile file = web.GetFile(attachments.UrlPrefix + fileName);
    // Do something ...
}
```

Comment: Wish I saw this post of yours before I implemented the 1000 line version :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an interesting look at things : http://www.binarywave.com/blogs/eshupps/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=26

This tells you how to get to the file - beyond just the string as Ian Kemp mentioned.

As the author of this post rights, its totally illogical and a pain in the neck, but I guess... Just another reason why MOSS stinks.